# select data from multiple tables with join group by, in one mysql query

Tags: mysql

table-1 Bill

```
| bill_id| date      | supplier_id |amount|
| 101    | 2019-03-16| 1570        |1000  |
| 102    | 2019-05-20| 1570        |2500  |
```

table-2 payment

```
| bill_id| date       | paid|
| 101    | 2019-03-17 | 800   |
| 101    | 2019-05-20 | 150   |
```

Expected result

```
| supplier_id |bill_id |amount|Paid | Balance|
| 1570        | 101    |1000  | 950 | 50     |
| 1570        | 102    |2500  | 0   | 2500   |
```

how do i achieve this

Comment: Why there is no supplier_id in table-2

Comment: supplier_id is already captured on the table-1, should it also be in table 1?

Comment: simply join the two tables on bill_id . Then you can add the sum and group by bill_id

Comment: From where paid and balance came?

Comment: paid is from payments table, balance is the difference of bill amount and total paid

Comment: Please show us what you've tried (assuming you've tried anything)

Comment: Do you means `amount` from payments table or it is not visible in your question?

Comment: amount in payment table is paid amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pre-aggregate `payment`

```
SELECT p.bill_id
     , SUM(p.amount) AS paid
  FROM payment p 
 GROUP BY p.bill_id
```

Then use that query as an inline view ...

```
SELECT b.supplier_id
     , b.bill_id
     , b.amount
     , IFNULL(q.paid,0)            AS paid 
     , b.amount - IFNULL(q.paid.0) AS balance  
  FROM bill b
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT p.bill_id
              , SUM(p.amount) AS paid
           FROM payment p 
          GROUP BY p.bill_id
       ) q
    ON q.bill_id = b.bill_id
 ORDER
    BY b.supplier_id
     , b.bill_id
```

---

Note that we aren't given any guarantee about uniqueness of `bill_id` in `bill` table. It looks like it might be the primary key, but that's just a guess. If that's not unique, then the results from this query are likely not going to be what we want.

Notice that we are using an outer join (the `LEFT` keyword) so the query will return rows for `bill` for which there are no matching rows in `payment`.  The `IFNULL` wrapper is shorthand way of converting a NULL value (which we would get if there isn't a matching row in payment) into a zero.

Comment: *"The IFNULL wrapper is shorthand way of converting a NULL value "*  i believe the `IFNULL(q.paid.0)` is simply equal to `CASE WHEN q.paid IS NOT NULL THEN q.paid ELSE 0 END` i could be wrong as i never used `IFNULL()`